# how to create mobile based application in asp.net

Tags: windows-mobile

how to create asp.net application that can be run on any windows mobile... 
what are h/w and s/w requirements for that?
and list of available  windows mobile in current market ???

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any seperate hardware for it.  Check this question for more information : [Creating a mini-site in ASP.NET that works on Blackberry, Windows Mobile, and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424/creating-a-mini-site-in-asp-net-that-works-on-blackberry-windows-mobile-and-iph)